# Is it possible to pass a script to awk inside a shell variable?

Tags: shell, awk

Is it possible to store an awk script inside a shell variable; for example:

```
export script="'{printf(\$2); printf("\"\\n\"");}'"

echo $script
'{printf($2); printf("\n");}'
```

The script functions properly when I call it directly as such:

```
awk '{printf($2); printf("\n");}' testFile.txt
prints proper output
```

When I try and pass the script as a shell variable, I run into issues.

```
awk $script testFile.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> ' <<< 
    missing }
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

I get a slightly different error when I wrap the variable in double quotes

```
awk "$script" testFile.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> ' <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

I'm still learning exactly how shell expansions work, I would appreciate any suggestions about what I am missing here.

Comment: Why are you storing awk script in an environment variable. That may work for a simple `print` command but would run into many problems for any meaningful script. It is better to store awk script in a file and use `awk -f script.awk`

Comment: To put it another way: Q) `Is it possible to shoot yourself in the foot with a shotgun`? A) `Sure, just hold it this way...`. Ask a new question explaining **what** you're trying to do rather than **how** you're trying to do it (by storing segments of awk script in variables and calling awk to execute them - shudder!) and we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error in your quoting

```
export script='{printf($2); printf("\n");}'
awk "${script}" YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the proper answer to this, but a very ugly (and probably unstable depending on the `$script` contents) workaround would be:

```
echo $script | awk '{print "awk "$0" testFile.txt"}' | bash
```

This is just printing the contents of `$script` in an `awk` statement that is then executed by bash. I am not particularly proud of this, but maybe it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you type

```
awk '{printf($2); printf("\n");}' testFile.txt
```

awk only sees `{printf($2); printf("\n");}` -- the shell removes the quotes
(see [Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quote-Removal) in the bash manual)

Heed @NeronLeVelu's answer.